# Scheme: Detecting duplicate elements in a list

Tags: list, set, scheme, chez-scheme

Does R6RS or Chez Scheme v7.9.4 have a library function to check if a list contains duplicate elements?

Alternatively, do either have any built in functionality for sets (which dis-allow duplicate elements)?  So far, I've only been able to find an example [here](http://www.scheme.com/tspl4/examples.html#./examples:s15).

The problem with that is that it doesn't appear to actually be part of the Chez Scheme library.  Although I *could* write my own version of this, I'd much rather use a well known, tested, and maintained library function - especially given how basic an operation this is.

So a simple "use these built-in functions" or a "no built-in library implements this" will suffice.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SRFI 1 on list processing has a `delete-duplicates` function](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#delete-duplicates) (so you could use that and check the length afterward) and may well have other functions you might find useful.

Comment: Thanks - looks like this would be a useful function.  Any idea when SRFI 1 will make it into Chez Scheme?  It already seems to have much of what this SRFI has to offer, but I'm not seeing delete-duplicates anywhere in v7.9.4.

Comment: I use PLT and I don't know anything about Chez, but many SRFIs should be available for any popular Scheme implementation; they're basically the big standard libraries for Scheme.  Google found this immediately: https://code.launchpad.net/~scheme-libraries-team/scheme-libraries/srfi These SLS (Scheme library source) files should be loadable via Chez, perhaps like this: http://www.scheme.com/csug8/libraries.html

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like this would probably work, although I haven't had a chance to download enough source to try loading it into Chez.

Answer (score 3):

Kyle,

Awhile back I needed to use a few SRFIs with Chez Scheme. A few that a converted for use with Chez Scheme (including SRFI-1) are at:

http://github.com/dharmatech/chez-srfi

After you add the path to 'chez-srfi' to your CHEZSCHEMELIBDIRS, you can import SRFI-1:

> (import (srfi :1))

Ed

Comment: This looks really useful, but I keep getting "Exception: library (srfi :1) not found" when I try the import command in the scheme interpreter.  I've tried setting CHEZSCHEMELIBDIRS, running with --libdirs, and running scheme from .../chez-srfi, but it's always the same result.

I'm not sure if this is related, but git didn't seem to like the files containing '*' when I cloned the repository.

Comment: Yikes, sorry for not responding earlier; I haven't checked stack overflow much lately. Are you on Windows? Unfortunately those srfi libraries use a naming convention which isn't supported on Windows (crazy I know...). I'm thinking about putting out copy of that collection which uses "portable" names.

Comment: No problem.  I am on Windows, so you can count at least one fan if you get a chance to release the portable version of the library :)